# Fix [correlative-comparitives]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

The tag [correlative-comparitives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correlative-comparitives) should be changed to [correlative-comparatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correlative-comparatives) because the former isn't properly spelled.

I was going to do it myself, but then I realized there's a tag synonym that probably shouldn't be messed with so I need a moderator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, this should [all be fixed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correlative-comparitives?sort=newest&pageSize=50) now.